# Django Help - Basic Setup and Basic Functionality

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

Done my due diligence and still having issues.  Here is my goal.  I'm using Django with Python to create a website with some custom coded features.  The problem I'm having is this.  I've tried these tutorials: http://matthewdaly.co.uk/blog/2013/12/28/django-blog-tutorial-the-next-generation-part-1/
http://ferretfarmer.net/2013/09/05/tutorial-real-time-chat-with-django-twisted-and-websockets-part-1/ (would prefer to use just django and no twisted but open to anything.
Next to last is: http://www.djangorocks.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-basic-blog-in-django/starting-your-application.html for blogs
And finally: creating a company site with blog, news pasting, etc. Most of which I can get via models as i have done in the past.

I've made progress: But I'm stuck at this part.  When I try to run python manage.py runserver i get a huge error like this:

```
ages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 113, in __i nit__
[shenk@LUCY2 mytest]$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
          execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "c:\Python27\lib\site-          packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",   line
190, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
40, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "c:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-       packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", 
line 14, in <module>
from django.db.migrations.executor import MigrationExecutor
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",     line 6,
in <module>
    from .loader import MigrationLoader
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line    10,
in <module>
from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 9,
    in <module>
    class MigrationRecorder(object):
    File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 23
, in MigrationRecorder
  class Migration(models.Model):
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 24
, in Migration
  app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line
  1081, in __init__
  super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line
 161, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
   File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 48, in  __ge
tattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 44, in _set
up
  self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-pack
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not   be
empty.
```

Please excuse the formatting it is not cooperating 100%, working pretty good though.

Anyway I want to create a site with django and add on to it a bunch of hard coded basic modules which I can do. What I need help with as I believe I mentioned is why I cant do python manage.py runserver?  Or the other question I had was the tutorials I found for blogs and such on Django were either out of date or did not work well.  Please guide me towards the best way to create a company website with Django.  For now I need basic skills similar to word press without and plugins (comments, blog, etc.) I can add more advanced functionality myself once this is working.  The info on the Django Doc's only works like 20% of the time.

Any help would be appreciated, my preferred answer is a bit of an explanmation how to use it, as well as what could be causing my runserver issues.

Any response is much appreciated.  I know this isn't the place, but send me a message on SO and perhaps we can work out payment in order to learn from you, get the base application done.  After that I can write the other modules myself.  (Yes, you'll be complicated and you can telecommute as I'm in PA outside Philly.

P.S. I'm an advanced C/C++ dev, a bit of C#, JS, Java, and mainly Python.

If you need any more info I can help.  I'm great with python and even .NET MVC but django is a bit different so any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says you've not configured the `SECRET_KEY` setting. You need to set the value of the `SECRET_KEY` variable in `your_app_name/settings.py` - if you used the command `python manage.py startproject` to create your Django project, it should have done this for you.

See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#secret-key

Answer (score 0):

open settings.py

add

```
SECRET_KEY = "IWANTDJANGO4SUMREASON"
```

to the bottom

Comment: that said in general I prefer flask to django ... since it does less "magic"

Answer (score 0):

According to your error log, you've improperly configured your Django application. `The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.` Please check your `settings.py` which is loaded by `manage.py` and make sure the [`SECRET_KEY`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-SECRET_KEY) contains an appropriate value. That should get you somewhere further.

On the other hand, I would suggest reading the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/) aswell as follow the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/) on how to get started. These are more often up-to-date and follow the official guidelines.